# How to tag different parts in image using CSS3/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am building an interactive educational small app, where I help kids discover the different parts of body.

http://www.easypacelearning.com/images/TheWholeBody.jpg

Technically, I want to know how can I select some parts in the image, to let users click on a portion of an image and link to a new more specific image.

Example: I am putting the body of human as a background, and I would like to click on an eye, it would pop-up and say it's an eye.

How can I get points so I can hover using the mouse to recognize the part ..

```
function getData() {
        return {
          'Head': {
            color:  ...
            points: ..
          }, 
'body': {
            color:  ...
            points: ..
          },
'leg': {
            color:  ...
            points: ..
          }
}
}
```

Link that I use to experiment : 
http://jsfiddle.net/ozgsvc61/1/

Comment: I would use some invisible elements positioned above the correct areas of the image.

Comment: Yes, but how can I place that ? should I manipulate them using margin/padding ..

Comment: It would probably be easiest if you wrap your image and your "anchors" in a div, then absolutely position your "anchors"

Comment: Yes! I am trying to learn that, for example in this tutorial, the writer is showing how to place capitals in the map.  (http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/). Can you give a hit !

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with an "[Image Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map)". This is a long forgotten feature of HTML.
To create linkable areas in your image, you use the `<map/>` element along with [`<area/>` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/area).

The `<area/>` elements, like the name suggests, define clickable areas in an image, and you can give them a 'polygon' shape, which sounds like what you're looking for.

A simple example:

```
<map name="body-parts">
   <area shape="poly" coords="..." href="#eyes" />
</map>
```

**EDIT**:
I don't think you can listen to `click` events with this, but you can definitely use [`hashchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/hashchange) event.

Comment: Woah, +1 for the archaeology :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add elements to you image and position them absolute like this:

```
#eye {
    position: absolute;
    height: 10px;  // size of area
    width: 10px;
    top: 20px;    // position
    left: 20px;
    cursor: pointer; // make it "feel" clickable

    // maybe you want to make a circle instead of a rectangle, you can do this with
    // border-radius (thanks to J148)
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Now you can use JS to get the click and display anything you want, in JQuery e.g.:

```
$('#eye').click(function(){ 
    // this is an eye !!!
});
```

Its maybe easier to use a data attribute to get the content easier.

```
<div class="area" data-content="This is an eye"></div>
```

In JQuery:

```
$('.area').click(function(){
    content = $(this).data("content");
    // show content in any way
});
```

Comment: however, this only supports rectangular regions.

Comment: ...and elliptical regions (border-radius)

Comment: i added this to my answer above :)